# Kubernetes NetworkPolicies refused connection

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I try to create a situation which is shown in the picture.

[image]

```
kubectl run frontend --image=nginx --labels="app=frontend" --port=30081 --expose
kubectl run backend --image=nginx --labels="app=backend" --port=30082 --expose
kubectl run database --image=nginx --labels="app=database" --port=30082
```

I created network policy which should block all ingress and egress access which do not have specific label definition.

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: access-nginx
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
     app: frontend
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
    matchLabels:
      app: database
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: frontend
        matchLabels:
          app: backend
        matchLabels:
          app: database
  egress:
  - to
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: frontend
        matchLabels:
          app: backend
        matchLabels:
          app: database
  - ports:
    - port: 53
      protocol: UDP
    - port: 53
      protocol: TCP
```

I tried to connect to pod frontend without label(command 1) and with correct label(command 2) as is shown below.

- kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --rm -it --restart=Never -- wget
  -O- http://frontend:30081 --timeout 2
- kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --rm -it --restart=Never
  --labels=app=frontend -- wget -O- http://frontend:30081 --timeout 2

I expected that first command which do not use label will be blocked and second command will allow communication but after pressed the second command i see output "wget: can't connect to remote host (10.109.223.254): Connection refused". Did I define network policy incorrectly?

Comment: Please provide kubernetes version and how your launch kubernetes.

Comment: It is version v.1.18.0. I try it online in this page https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes/playground.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) about Network Policy

> **Prerequisites**
>
> Network policies are implemented by the [network plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/). To use network policies, you must be using a networking solution which supports NetworkPolicy. Creating a NetworkPolicy resource without a controller that implements it will have no effect.

As far as I know flannel, which is used by katacoda does not support network policy.

```
controlplane $ kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-66bff467f8-4tmhm                  1/1     Running   0          16m
coredns-66bff467f8-v2dbj                  1/1     Running   0          16m
etcd-controlplane                         1/1     Running   0          16m
katacoda-cloud-provider-58f89f7d9-brnk2   1/1     Running   8          16m
kube-apiserver-controlplane               1/1     Running   0          16m
kube-controller-manager-controlplane      1/1     Running   0          16m
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-h5lrd               1/1     Running   1          16m
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-sdl4b               1/1     Running   0          16m
kube-keepalived-vip-gkhbz                 1/1     Running   0          16m
kube-proxy-6gd8d                          1/1     Running   0          16m
kube-proxy-zkldz                          1/1     Running   0          16m
kube-scheduler-controlplane               1/1     Running   1          16m
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/coreos/flannel#:%7E:text=Networking%20details&text=Flannel%20is%20responsible%20for%20providing,traffic%20is%20transported%20between%20hosts.&text=For%20network%20policy%2C%20other%20projects%20such%20as%20Calico%20can%20be%20used.)

> Flannel is focused on networking. For network policy, other projects such as Calico can be used.

Additionally there is nice [tutorial](https://itnext.io/benchmark-results-of-kubernetes-network-plugins-cni-over-10gbit-s-network-updated-april-2019-4a9886efe9c4) which show which CNI support network policy.

[image]

So I would say it´s not possible to do on katacoda playground.